# Can I use all the cards in a hand in Omaha hi-low?

Tags: rules, omaha-hi-lo

Player A has  A,2,Q,K.
Board cards are 3,4,6,K,Q. 
Can he or she win low with a A,2,3,4,6? Change cards for hi and win hi A,Q Q,K,K?

Comment: Sorry the game is Omaha hi low

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a player can use any combination of two cards from their hand and 3 from the board in Omaha Hi-low to make a complete hand, and they do now have to be the same cards for the high and low hands.

In your example for the high hand, it would actually be KKQQ6.

Comment: You mean KKQQ6?

Comment: @Paparazzi yes, fixed.